# How to manually apply styles from particular style sheet to an element?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a form which is linked with various stylesheets. I have two stylesheets which has styles for the select tag. So its getting conflicted when i link both stylesheets.

For example

I have style1.css and style2.css which contains styles for select tag. And i have two select tags with ids select1 and select2.

I want only the style from style1.css to be applied to select1 and styles from style2.css to select2. How can i do it ?

I can't specify the styles to those particular id, because it will affect other select tags too.

How can i make the styles of different style sheets to work only in a particular place?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible with client side techniques - once the style sheets are loaded, it's out of our hands. However, if you have server side language at your disposal you can "merge" those style sheets and serve one final style sheet filtered as you want.

Comment: This it not possible without changing the CSS selector in either of the stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3's `:not()` selector. For example, in `style2.css`, you would write:

```
select:not(#select1) {
    // styling here will be applied to all selects except select1
}
```

But in reality you should just keep all the styling for the `select` tag in one CSS document. This way you can more easily control the conflicts.

Comment: Very good solution, there is only one problem: `:not()` selector is not supported by IE8 and earlier. IE9 and other browsers support it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS works in such way that last settings are the most important. So you can link `style1.css` first, then `style2.css` and **in the end** of `style2.css` you can define styles for `select1`:

```
#select1
{
  /* styles */
}
```

It will not affect any other elements, only `select1`.

But generally you should merge styles for selects in one stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can define class name for style1 id as `class="style-one"` and then define the styles by giving `!important` tag to element styles.
Like this:

```
.style-one{border:none !important;}
```

And moreover you can define this class in any of the style sheets you are using without changing the order.:)